# Convolution vs signal resolution

Tags: fortran, convolution

I realized that the resolution of the input signal dramatically affects the results of the convolution. I'm wondering if there is a way to compensate somehow for this. Let me give you an example:

Lets take the Sersic equation:
[Sersic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C5wF.gif)
with, for example, [parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5DZw.gif).

Now we solve this equation both for a R step of 0.1 and 0.01. For example for the 1st point (R=0) we get \mu(0) = 9.82.

The next step is to convolve the data, after converting it into counts (to convert it to counts we can use this simple equation: Data(R) = 10^((\mu(R)-25)/(-2.5)). I'm using the bellow mentioned subroutine that I wrote but I tried with others and I get the same result (the PSF is Moffat with FWHM = 0.5 arcsec and its constructed in a way that its total area equals 1):

```
  sum1 = 0
  DO i = 1,n
    sum1 = 0
    g = i
    DO f = 1,i
      sum1(f) = Data(f)*PSF(g)   
      g = i - f
    ENDDO
    convData(i) = sum(sum1)
  ENDDO 
  convData = convData(n:1:-1)
```

So, for this example, for the data with 0.1 resolution after convolution (and after reconverting the counts to \mu) I get for \mu(0)* = 13.52. For the data with 0.01 resolution I get \mu(0)* = 15.52. This is 2 magnitudes difference!! What am I doing wrong or how can I somehow compensate for this effect?

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Convolution with what kind of kernel? What is the meaning of the result? Note this does not look like a programming problem. You may have more luck at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com but do not crosspost. If you ask there, delete the question here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't fundamentally a programming problem.  @VladimirF's advice to seek help on that other site is good.

Comment: its actually both (math and programing). the mathematical part serves only to draw the data sets. tell me how would you convolve a data set? maybe another routine for the convolution will solve the problem.

Comment: and the kernel is moffat with fwhm = 0.5 (for example). the meaning is: if we are observing an elliptical galaxy its light distribution is given by the sersic equation. but if you have turbulence in the atmosphere or your telescope its not that good, then the data will be convolved. usually in this cases we astronomers use moffat as the PSF distribution. the idea is to unconvolve the data in order to recover the true light profile of the galaxy.